# My array doesn't return anything. For shopping1.java

Tags: java

I tried to debug it but I have no clue what code I'm loosing. Mind checking up for me?  I want to add Item Names, price and quantity into `ITEM[]` array but when I try to print , it doesn't return anything

item.java

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Item {
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;

    public Item(String itemName, double itemPrice, int numPurchased) {
        name = itemName;
        price = itemPrice;
        quantity = numPurchased;
    }

    public String toString() {
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return (name + "\t" + fmt.format(price) + "\t" + quantity + "\t"
                + fmt.format(price * quantity));
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

}
```

ShoppingCart.java

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
public class ShoppingCart {
private int itemCount; // total number of items in the cart
private double totalPrice; // total price of items in the cart
private int capacity; // current cart capacity
private Item[] cart = new Item[capacity];

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// Creates an empty shopping cart with a capacity of 5 items.
// -----------------------------------------------------------
public ShoppingCart()
{
capacity = 5;
itemCount = 0;
totalPrice = 0.0;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------
// Adds an item to the shopping cart.
// -------------------------------------------------------
public void addToCart(String itemName, double price, int quantity)
{if(itemCount==cart.length)
 increaseSize();
else{
cart[itemCount]=new Item(itemName, price, quantity);
totalPrice += (totalPrice * quantity);
itemCount++;
}
}
// -------------------------------------------------------
// Returns the contents of the cart together with
// summary information.
// -------------------------------------------------------

public String toString()
{
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
String contents = "\nShopping Cart\n";
contents += "\nItem\t\tUnit Price\tQuantity\tTotal\n";
for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
contents += cart[i].toString() + "\n";
contents += "\nTotal Price: " + fmt.format(totalPrice);
contents += "\n";
return contents;
 }
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// Increases the capacity of the shopping cart by 3
// ---------------------------------------------------------
private void increaseSize()
{Item[] temp = new Item[cart.length + 3];
for (int num = 0; num < cart.length; num++)
{
temp[num] = cart[num];
cart = temp;

}

}



}
```

Shopping1.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Shopping1 {


 public static void main(String[] args)
{
 String answer="y";
 ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
 while(answer=="y")
 {
 System.out.println("Enter the Name, Price, and Quantity of Item:");
 Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
 String name = scan.next();
 double price = scan.nextDouble();
 int quantity = scan.nextInt();

 cart.addToCart(name, price, quantity);

 String printout = cart.toString();
 System.out.println(printout);
 System.out.println("Do you want to continue? y/n");
 Scanner ans = new Scanner (System.in);
 answer = ans.next();
 }
 System.out.println("thank you !");
}
}
```

My output was:

> Enter the Name, Price, and Quantity of Item:
>   yuvin
>   3
>   2

```
Shopping Cart

Item        Unit Price  Quantity    Total

Total Price: MYR0.00
```

> Do you want to continue? y/n
>   n
>   thank you !

While I was expecting some return of the array which I just inserted

Comment: Please indent. More difficult to read without it.

Comment: Consider adding that to the question itself; it's essentially illegible in a comment. And please indent.

Comment: sorry im a beginner and i will learn how to adapt to the forum. help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line

```
private Item[] cart = new Item[capacity];
```

is executed prior to the constructor, therefore capacity will be zero at that time and you will get an array without space for elements ...

//edit:

additionally there is a flaw in that addToCart method ...

if (itemCount==cart.length) is true, the item you are about to add is discarded, because you only increase the array size ... you should increase the array size and then add the item ...

Comment: i made some changes on my code and i changed shoppingcart.java private int capacity=5; private Item[] cart = new Item[capacity]; {if(itemCount==cart.length) increaseSize(); cart[itemCount]=new Item(itemName, price, quantity); totalPrice += (price * quantity); itemCount++; } totalPrice += (price * quantity); thank for all the help and i realised the IF statement before i change did not even executes once that why array element was not added.

Answer (score 0):

totalPrice is always 0 in this line:

```
totalPrice += (totalPrice * quantity);
```

I think you want:

> totalPrice += (price * quantity);

Comment: Thx alot .. but still after i change it. the output is the same.      run:
Enter the Name, Price, and Quantity of Item:
yuvin
3
2

Shopping Cart

Item  Unit Price Quantity Total

Total Price: MYR0.00

Do you want to continue? y/n

Comment: im expecting some ("yuvin"     3     2 )   under item, unitprice and quantity

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate cart:

```
private Item[] cart = new Item[capacity];
```

capacity is null. (setting you up for a **NullPointerException**). When you go to instantiate it, you need to be sure capacity has some type of value besides null. How it is the size of cart is 0,  so you are unable to actually add anything to it.

Consider using an ArrayList instead so the size is dynamic??

Comment: `capacity` is a primitive `int`, so it can never be null. At the time that `cart` is initialized, `capacity` is zero.

Comment: ahhh, thats right. my bad, I was thinking of `Integer`.

Comment: thanks alot. that my problem. i instantiate it with a number to begin

Answer (score 0):

You should test each method individually, and make sure that it does what you expect, rather than trying to debug the program as a single mass. For example, this method:

```
private void increaseSize()
{
    Item[] temp = new Item[cart.length + 3];
    for (int num = 0; num < cart.length; num++)
    {
        temp[num] = cart[num];
        cart = temp;
    }
}
```

does not do what you want: it will increase the size of `cart`, yes, but it will also set every element of `cart` to `null`, except for `cart[0]`. If you had tested this method, you would have seen this issue.